# Css selector/xpath

Tags: css, xpath, selector

I am attempting to find the Xpath of this CSS selector

```
div.price div:nth-of-type(1)
```

I have tried this, however i'm still struggling to add the second part

```
//div[@class="price"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
//div[@class="price"]//div[position() = 1]
```

This should pick the first div (by `position() = 1`) that is a child of the div with `class="price"` attribute.

Remember to be careful with `@class=` as CSS class selectors support elements with multiple classes. If you want to go full-pedantic, use

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' price ')]
```